# Zen Cart - if this is checkout page

Tags: php, checkout, zen-cart

Does Zen Cart have the functionality to check if this is the checkout page?
I know for the home page we can have something like:

```
<?php if ($this_is_home_page) { ?>
  ......
<?php } ?>
```

Do they have documentation to search this and other php functionality available?

Thanks in advance.

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use this:

```
if ($current_page_base == "checkout_shipping") {
```

note that you may have to `global $current_page_base;` depending on your context.